# C# Console Application: Preventing Control-C from being printed?

Tags: c#, console-application, control-characters

I have a console app, and I want to capture Control-C and shutdown gracefully.

I have the following code:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler((o, e) =>
{
   Logger.Log("Control+C hit. Shutting down.");
   resetEvent.Set();
});
```

And the output windows shows:

> 6/16/2010 3:24:34 PM: Control+C hit. Shutting down. 
>   ^C

Is there a way to prevent the control-c character `^C` from appearing? It's not a **huge** deal, but for some reason Ill be fixated on it because I'm anal like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a console application I would use `Environment.Exit` to signal that the application is exiting and this way stopping the `^C` from being print.

You could even provide a specific error code to symbolize that the user pressed <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.

```
static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Control+C hit. Shutting down."); 

    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler((o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Control+C hit. Shutting down.");
    Environment.Exit(0);
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is not necessarily a solution you want to implement, it does prevent the ^C from being displayed:

```
static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Control+C hit. Shutting down.");     
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```